# understanding this C++ module?

Tags: c++

Given  a type `Money` that is a structured type with two `int` fields, dollars and cents. Assume that an array named `monthlySales` with 12 elements, each of type `Money` has been declared and initialized.

Assume that a `Money`-variable `yearlySales` has also been declared. Write the necessary code that traverses the `monthlySales`-array  and adds it all up and stores the resulting total in `yearlySales`. Be sure make sure that `yearlySales` ends up with a valid value, i.e. a value  of cents that is less than  100.

Now i'm not asking for the answer but, i'm asking how do i approach it. simply because i'm not sure how to address the question like how to code it. I have understand the first paragraph of the question respectively. here is my snippet of code. now im just stuck on how to compute it. i just need a bit of guidance. Thanks!
the code i have so far, accesses the array I have of 12 elements and assigns them random numbers of dollars and cents respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

    struct Money
    {
        int dollars,cents;
    };


    int main()
    {
        Money monthlySales[12], yearlySales;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            monthlySales[i].cents =rand()%99;
            monthlySales[i].dollars =rand();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Use the `<random>` header instead of `rand`.

Comment: Why are you doing `rand() % 99`? There is no where in the reqs it says to use `rand()`

Comment: I was just testing it that's all making sure i approached it correctly. @Smac89

Comment: @chris - `rand()` is good enough here; there's no need for the extra effort required to use the stuff from `<random>`. Of course, `rand()%99` should be `rand()%100`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, Is it really so much extra effort? Probably one less include and 2 more lines of actual code of setup to generate the random number is only one extra line.

Comment: @chris - it takes a bit more than just adding a header and some code. You have to understand what's there; for someone who isn't familiar with `<random>`, that's far more work than using `rand()` for a throwaway test.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I'll agree it does take more getting used to, but it's pretty much a one time thing. [STL](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) does a good job of explaining it with his "you only really need like two things out of all of these unless you have a specific reason for others" approach.

Comment: @chris - it also could require updating your compiler or installing a third-party library. Again, a total waste of time for a throwaway test.

Answer (score 3):

> Write the necessary code that traverses the monthlySalesarray  and
>   adds it all up and stores the resulting total in yearlySales. Be sure
>   make sure that yearlySales ends up with a valid value , i.e. a value 
>   of cents that is less than  100.

```
Money monthlySales[12], yearlySales;

yearlySales.cents   = 0;
yearlySales.dollars = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    yearlySales.cents += monthlySales[i].cents;     // Add up the cents
    yearlySales.dollars += monthlySales[i].dollars; // Add up the dollars

    yearlySales.dollars += yearlySales.cents / 100; // If cents > 100, increase dollars appropriately.
    yearlySales.cents = yearlySales.cents % 100;    // If cents > 100, set it to the remainder.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     //to compute Sum
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            yearlySales.cents +=monthlySales[i].cents;//keeps adding yearlySales cents for each month
            yearlySales.dollars +=monthlySales[i].dollars;//keeps adding yearlySales dollars
        }
   //if cents 100 convert it into dollars eg:720cents is convereted to 7$ 20 cents and 7 dollars is added       to yearly dollars
    if(yearlySales.cents > =100)
    {
    yearlySales.dollars+=yearlySales.cents/100;
    yearlySales.cents=yearlySales.cents%100;
    }
```

Comment: i appreciate the help i just got tricked up thinking a actual values were being computed. @Kaushik.

Answer (score 0):

This works too!

```
float dollar = 0;
float cent = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    dollar += monthlySales[i].dollars;
    cent += monthlySales[i].cents;
    do {
        if (cent > 100 ) {
        dollar += 1;
        cent -= 100;
            }
    }while (cent > 100);
}

yearlySales.dollars = dollar;
yearlySales.cents = cent;
```